# Vibrancy Continued not working in my windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my windows 10 I had download Vibrancy Continued for the first time. But it not works.

I did all the must needed steps mentioned in the extention download page. Still it is not working.

[it is looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJNfe.png)

if you know anybody what is the problem please letme know. thnaks in advance